# What are our sources for Longinus' De sublimitate?

Tags: poetry

What I am interested in is the part where he quotes Sappho, or, even more specifically, l. 3 of the second stanza of the quoted poem, and in particular the verb in that line. This starts from [this post](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/about-l-3-of-the-second-stanza-of-sapphos-%e1%bd%a8%ce%b4%e1%bd%b4-%ce%b5%e1%bc%b0%cf%82-%e1%bc%88%ce%bd%ce%b1%ce%ba%cf%84%cf%89%cf%81%ce%af%ce%b1%ce%bd-ode-to-anactoria). The answer there told me the poem comes from Longinus, so I was wondering what the manuscript tradition for that part is. I found something about a Parisian codex. Quoting the post linked above:

> [This edition of Longinus *On the sublime*](https://ia800309.us.archive.org/27/items/LonginusOnTheSublimeTheGreekTextEditedAfterTheParisManuscriptWith/longinus_sublime_Roberts.pdf) reports the text as:
>   [image: amended text in the above link]
>   that is with `ἔς σ' ἴδω`, and adds this critical note:
>   [image: critical note to the poem in the above link]
>   It is Longinus's work following a Paris manuscript.

Are there other sources (maybe available online) for that passage? What do those other sources have to say about that line?

**Note**

Questions about reconstructions of texts (Latin or Ancient Greek, as long as AG is allowed here) might be borderline off-topic, seen as they typically are not so much about the language as about the reading and emendation of the various sources. If a question like this is considered off-topic, please warn me, because I have a number of these that I haven't yet formulated but will surely have to post. After all, I'm sure I'll need inputs for my blog posts about Sappho's poems, which I "restored" and translated (all of them) years ago into Latin English and Italian as poems, keeping or imitating the original meters. So better warn me now than after I post tens of these :).

Comment: You have noticed, presumably, that the editor lists the manuscripts and justifies his editorial method in the Appendix (pp. 163 sqq.)

Comment: And specifically to the poem by Sappho pp. 172-3.

Comment: @fdb actually I hadn't noticed that. So we have 11 or maybe 12 manuscripts. The question is: what does each of these have for that line? The critical note says one of the Paris codes has ὠς γὰρ σ' ἴδω, but I can't tell which of the four, or if any of the others differ.

Comment: I think you need to look out for the more modern editions of Sappho’s poems, notably: Lobel, E.; Page, D. L., eds. (1955). Poetarum Lesbiorum fragmenta. Oxford: Clarendon Press, and Voigt, Eva-Maria (1971). Sappho et Alcaeus. Fragmenta. Amsterdam: Polak & van Gennep.

Comment: @fdb Are any of those available online? I cannot seem to find Lobel-Page or Voigt. Except as Google books which do not even automatically preview. Time to look for Polak and Van Gennep.

Comment: Nope, same result.

Comment: I think you need to go to a university library.

Comment: @fdb My situation prevents that. I mean, I have a muscle problem so I cannot walk long distances, which means the only accessible uni libraries for me are those of my own uni, and I wouldn't really expect Milan-Bicocca University to have that in their libraries, seen as there is no course in Classical stuff that I am aware of. Maybe I can have a look at their online catalog, but I'm pretty skeptical. I take it they cannot be found online...

Comment: I do not believe Lobel-Page is online. If you don't mind waiting a bit for answers, I can snag one and try to answer your questions for you, but if your university library subscribes to InterLibraryLoan or some other shared service, I recommend getting L-P yourself and going from there.

Comment: @CMWeimer I honestly have no idea what my Uni library is subscribed to :). I never used it except as a studying place, and even that I only did some time ago. No I don't mind, and thanks. The only "deadlines" I have for getting answers are the dates I post on my blog, and even those posts can just be edited afterwards to include the info (or I just link the SE posts).

Comment: I'll try to stop by the library tomorrow and check out Voigt, will post then.

Answer (score 4):

This is a temporary answer, but here's the app crit for the Sappho from Lobel-Page:

[image]